# Clearing File Data before writing in Netlogo

Tags: file, file-io, append, netlogo

I am trying to output some data in a file and I can output the data in file easily. But when I output data second time in file, it gets appended with the previous data. What I want to do is to clear the previous data and insert only the new data without appending the new data with old data. Below is my code :

```
     file-open "savedgame.txt"

       foreach sort turtles [
    ask ? [
      file-print (turtlenumbers) // ; This appends the "turtlenumbers" with old data in
                                 //  ;  file (if any). I want to clear file before 
                                 //  ;writing "turtlenumbers" in the file


       file-print ""

    ]
  ] 
   file-close
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [`file-open` documentation in the NetLogo dictionnary](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#file-open):

> When opening a file in writing mode, all new data will be appended to
>   the end of the original file. If there is no original file, a new
>   blank file will be created in its place. (You must have write
>   permission in the file's directory.) **(If you don't want to append, but
>   want to replace the file's existing contents, use `file-delete` to
>   delete it first, perhaps inside a `carefully` if you're not sure whether
>   it already exists.)**

In other words, add this as your very first line:

```
carefully [ file-delete "savedgame.txt" ] [ ]
```